# c++ set cursor size over 32

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, cursor

im trying to set a cursor. the width and the height of the cursor is bigger than 32 px. but it just scale it down to 32px when i set it. 
 any idea?

Comment: How are you setting the cursor? Have you looked up the restrictions for a cursor on whatever method you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `LoadCursor` function, then I think you'll always get scaled to the standard size.

Try using [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(v=VS.85).aspx) with `IMAGE_CURSOR`, a desired size of (0,0), and do *not* use the `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` flag.

Comment: Hi Adrian, whilst you answer seemed to work for Ramilol, it does not appear to work for me. Would you be able to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098580/set-system-cursor-size) for if I am doing anything wrong? Thanks :)