# Maximum size of mouse cursor in Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8.1, gdi+, mouse-cursor

What is the maximum size of mouse cursor in Windows 8.1?

I load cursor from 1000x1000 .png file using GDI+:

```
Bitmap *image = Bitmap::FromStream(pStream);
UINT w = image->GetWidth(), h = image->GetHeight();

HBITMAP bmpMask;
HBITMAP bmpColor;
image->GetHBITMAP(Color(), &bmpMask);
image->GetHBITMAP(Color(), &bmpColor);

ICONINFO iconInfo;
iconInfo.fIcon = FALSE;
iconInfo.xHotspot = 0;
iconInfo.yHotspot = 0;
iconInfo.hbmMask = bmpMask;
iconInfo.hbmColor = bmpColor;

hCursor = ::CreateIconIndirect(&iconInfo);
```

If it will be necessary, ask me and I'll provide full source code of application.

In Windows 7 all is OK.
Cursor dimentions 1000x1000.

But there is strange thing - it scales on Windows 8.1 to 32x32 size.
Enabling compatibility modes doesn't help.
Is it OS limitation?

Thanks in advance for response.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I think that's `Visual C++`, apparently they're different. I tried, but got a "Suggested edit queue is full". Anyway, "Is it OS limitation?" - No, that's just the OS' default size. I don't know anything about this topic, but apparently it happens when you're not loading it right. Best I can do is provide [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098580/set-system-cursor-size), [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560710/c-set-cursor-size-over-32/3561375#3561375) and [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea).